How to record Long and short pages in the Log file
I want to record the long and short page information with page number in the log file, when  page contain the text contents less than or more than the text height
Log file shows, one occurrence like below, but "MWE" content having multiple short pages
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
How to record the information in the log file.
MWE
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\widowpenalty10000
\clubpenalty10000

\parskip0pt

\begin{document}

\noindent For instance, compared to viewing nonpainful pictures of others, viewing pictures of others who are in pain weakens individuals' performance in WM tasks (Chen et al. 2017). This effect may be attributed to the activation of common neural representations for self-pain and others' pain (Meng et al. 2013), as pain, signifying actual or potential injury, disrupts attention. The ``threat value of pain" hypothesis suggests that perceiving another's pain activates survival mechanisms, leading to avoidance behaviors, regardless of objective or subjective danger assessments (Coll et al. 2012). Thus, perceiving another's pain may induce vicarious anxiety about threats and danger, disrupting attention during WM tasks.

It is noteworthy that, within everyday experiences, the inter-action between cognitive and affective processes in individuals deserves closer scrutiny, as these processes might inter-relate rather than function separately. Some studies have examined the effects of WM on EfP and the impact of EfP on WM in separate experimental settings (Chen et al. 2017, Cui et al. 2017). How-ever, the bidirectional influence of WM on EfP response and EfP on WM performance within the same timeframe remains unex-plored. For instance, does a doctor's empathic response to seeing a stranger patient injured and bleeding differ when the doctor is under high work pressure compared to when they are relaxed and free of tasks? Additionally, if the doctor witnesses the injury and bleeding and then continues with a high cognitive load task, will their efficiency and performance be affected? Furthermore, if the injured person is the doctor's relative, will the empathic response and subsequent cognitive performance differ from those elicited by a stranger?
Humans, being inherently social, often find themselves in environments replete with diverse interpersonal relationships. An individual's cognitive and affective processes are influenced, to some extent, by the perceived SDs within these contexts (Nissan et al. 2015). SD encompasses an individual's perception or experience of distance from others (Li et al. 2020a), with varying levels among kin and strangers. Research indicates that partic-ipants rate higher pain intensity when imagining a loved one in pain compared to a stranger, with stronger brain region acti-vations related to EfP (Cheng et al. 2010). Similar studies have shown stronger left anterior insula activation when observing pain in the same social group versus different groups (Sheng and Han 2012). Both pain and EfP are associated with this brain region (Decety et al. 2012). Recent studies also demonstrate that empathy is foundational for altruistic behavior, biased toward socially close individuals (Fowler et al. 2021). Kin selection the-ory suggests that through empathy for kin, we can better meet their needs and engage in altruistic behavior, thereby increas-ing their chances of survival. This contributes to the survival and reproduction of kin, indirectly promoting the transmission of our own genes (Hamilton 1964). Thus, empathic responses to kin are typically stronger than those to strangers. In parallel, more distant SD accompanied by less worry and anxiety would then result in more abstract thinking (Smith and Trope 2006, Trope and Liberman 2010), which, in turn, facilitates the organization and manipulation of complex information, improving WM capabilities (Herzmann et al. 2011).

Based on the preceding research, it is clear that exploring the mutual influence of WM and EfP, as well as the interplay further resulting from the impact of SD, aids in our enhanced under-standing of how individuals concurrently engage in cognitive and affective processing to adapt to complex social environments in daily life. Therefore, in this study, we employed electroenhow WM and EfP are mutually influential, while exploring the role of SD, which has practical significance. Since EEG/ERP mea-surement offers a window into the temporal dynamics of neu-ral responses to observing others' pain and memory judgment, we gathered participants and compared their behavioral and EEG/ERP responses while they completed tasks that combined EfP and WM, where they processed pain perception and made memory judgments. According to earlier ERP


\enlargethispage{12pt}

For instance, compared to viewing nonpainful pictures of others, viewing pictures of others who are in pain weakens individuals' performance in WM tasks (Chen et al. 2017). This effect may be attributed to the activation of common neural representations for self-pain and others' pain (Meng et al. 2013), as pain, signifying actual or potential injury, disrupts attention. The ``threat value of pain" hypothesis suggests that perceiving another's pain activates survival mechanisms, leading to avoidance behaviors, regardless of objective or subjective danger assessments (Coll et al. 2012). Thus, perceiving another's pain may induce vicarious anxiety about threats and danger, disrupting attention during WM tasks.

It is noteworthy that, within everyday experiences, the inter-action between cognitive and affective processes in individuals deserves closer scrutiny, as these processes might inter-relate rather than function separately. Some studies have examined the effects of WM on EfP and the impact of EfP on WM in separate experimental settings (Chen et al. 2017, Cui et al. 2017). How-ever, the bidirectional influence of WM on EfP response and EfP on WM performance within the same timeframe remains unex-plored. For instance, does a doctor's empathic response to seeing a stranger patient injured and bleeding differ when the doctor is under high work pressure compared to when they are relaxed and free of tasks? Additionally, if the doctor witnesses the injury and bleeding and then continues with a high cognitive load task, will their efficiency and performance be affected? Furthermore, if the injured person is the doctor's relative, will the empathic response and subsequent cognitive performance differ from those elicited by a stranger?
Humans, being inherently social, often find themselves in environments replete with diverse interpersonal relationships. An individual's cognitive and affective processes are influenced, to some extent, by the perceived SDs within these contexts (Nissan et al. 2015). SD encompasses an individual's perception or experience of distance from others (Li et al. 2020a), with varying levels among kin and strangers. Research indicates that partic-ipants rate higher pain intensity when imagining a loved one in pain compared to a stranger, with stronger brain region acti-vations related to EfP (Cheng et al. 2010). Similar studies have shown stronger left anterior insula activation when observing pain in the same social group versus different groups (Sheng and Han 2012). Both pain and EfP are associated with this brain region (Decety et al. 2012). Recent studies also demonstrate that empathy is foundational for altruistic behavior, biased toward socially close individuals (Fowler et al. 2021). Kin selection the-ory suggests that through empathy for kin, we can better meet their needs and engage in altruistic behavior, thereby increas-ing their chances of survival. This contributes to the survival and reproduction of kin, indirectly promoting the transmission of our own genes (Hamilton 1964). Thus, empathic responses to kin are typically stronger than those to strangers. In parallel, more distant SD accompanied by less worry and anxiety would then result in more abstract thinking (Smith and Trope 2006, Trope and Liberman 2010), which, in turn, facilitates the organization and manipulation of complex information, improving WM capabilities (Herzmann et al. 2011).

Based on the preceding research, it is clear that exploring the mutual influence of WM and EfP, as well as the interplay further resulting from the impact of SD, aids in our enhanced under-standing of how individuals concurrently engage in cognitive and affective processing to adapt to complex social environments in daily life. Therefore, in this study, we employed electroenhow WM and EfP are mutually influential, while exploring the role of SD, which has practical significance. Since EEG/ERP mea-surement offers a window into the temporal dynamics of neu-ral responses to observing others' pain and memory judgment, we gathered participants and compared their behavioral and EEG/ERP responses while they completed tasks that combined EfP and WM, where they processed pain perception and made memory judgments. According to earlier ERP





For instance, compared to viewing nonpainful pictures of others, viewing pictures of others who are in pain weakens individuals' performance in WM tasks (Chen et al. 2017). This effect may be attributed to the activation of common neural representations for self-pain and others' pain (Meng et al. 2013), as pain, signifying actual or potential injury, disrupts attention. The ``threat value of pain" hypothesis suggests that perceiving another's pain activates survival mechanisms, leading to avoidance behaviors, regardless of objective or subjective danger assessments (Coll et al. 2012). Thus, perceiving another's pain may induce vicarious anxiety about threats and danger, disrupting attention during WM tasks.


\enlargethispage{-24pt}

It is noteworthy that, within everyday experiences, the inter-action between cognitive and affective processes in individuals deserves closer scrutiny, as these processes might inter-relate rather than function separately. Some studies have examined the effects of WM on EfP and the impact of EfP on WM in separate experimental settings (Chen et al. 2017, Cui et al. 2017). How-ever, the bidirectional influence of WM on EfP response and EfP on WM performance within the same timeframe remains unex-plored. For instance, does a doctor's empathic response to seeing a stranger patient injured and bleeding differ when the doctor is under high work pressure compared to when they are relaxed and free of tasks? Additionally, if the doctor witnesses the injury and bleeding and then continues with a high cognitive load task, will their efficiency and performance be affected? Furthermore, if the injured person is the doctor's relative, will the empathic response and subsequent cognitive performance differ from those elicited by a stranger?
Humans, being inherently social, often find themselves in environments replete with diverse interpersonal relationships. An individual's cognitive and affective processes are influenced, to some extent, by the perceived SDs within these contexts (Nissan et al. 2015). SD encompasses an individual's perception or experience of distance from others (Li et al. 2020a), with varying levels among kin and strangers. Research indicates that partic-ipants rate higher pain intensity when imagining a loved one in pain compared to a stranger, with stronger brain region acti-vations related to EfP (Cheng et al. 2010). Similar studies have shown stronger left anterior insula activation when observing pain in the same social group versus different groups (Sheng and Han 2012). Both pain and EfP are associated with this brain region (Decety et al. 2012). Recent studies also demonstrate that empathy is foundational for altruistic behavior, biased toward socially close individuals (Fowler et al. 2021). Kin selection the-ory suggests that through empathy for kin, we can better meet their needs and engage in altruistic behavior, thereby increas-ing their chances of survival. This contributes to the survival and reproduction of kin, indirectly promoting the transmission of our own genes (Hamilton 1964). Thus, empathic responses to kin are typically stronger than those to strangers. In parallel, more distant SD accompanied by less worry and anxiety would then result in more abstract thinking (Smith and Trope 2006, Trope and Liberman 2010), which, in turn, facilitates the organization and manipulation of complex information, improving WM capabilities (Herzmann et al. 2011).

Based on the preceding research, it is clear that exploring the mutual influence of WM and EfP, as well as the interplay further resulting from the impact of SD, aids in our enhanced under-standing of how individuals concurrently engage in cognitive and affective processing to adapt to complex social environments in daily life. Therefore, in this study, we employed electroenhow WM and EfP are mutually influential, while exploring the role of SD, which has practical significance. Since EEG/ERP mea-surement offers a window into the temporal dynamics of neu-ral responses to observing others' pain and memory judgment, we gathered participants and compared their behavioral and EEG/ERP responses while they completed tasks that combined EfP and WM, where they processed pain perception and made memory judgments. According to earlier ERP


\end{document}


overfull pages will generate overfull box warnings and underfull will generate underfull so it's not clear what more logging you want? You are making the pages longer or shorter which does not show in the frame that you print, and the final page is short without warning as the final page is always allowed to be short, \clearpage adds suitable glue.

or do you mean that you want \enlargethispage  to write to the log file each time it is used?

@DavidCarlisle   I need to write the information in the log file which page is not fully filled by content or exceeded the  text height except last page (whenever the page is not fully filled by content  up to the text height; either used or not \enlargethispage), for MWE purpose i used \enlargethispage to short the page

that is already logged as an over or underfull box so it isn't clear what else you need. The \enlargethispage makes the MWE very confusing as it changes the target height of the page so you can't tell by looking at the output which pages are short and which are long

Are you maybe looking for the [42] etc marks in log file which tell you which page you are on?

@DavidCarlisle,
@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
My expectation is write the info in the log file like  Warning: page [1] is shorter then the actual text height or   Warning: page [1] is longer then the actual text height

@pdy-ind Did you already try to work with the existing page markers in the log file to see on which page the warning is located?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, No i didn't tried, and i stuck and no idea about where to modify

@pdy-ind You don't need to modify anything. The .log file already has markers like [1, [2 etc. which you can use to see where you are in the document.

is possible to record the info  like Warning: page [1] is shorter then the actual text height or Warning: page [1] is longer then the actual text height ?

that is exactly what the over and under full box warnings do. By using \enlargethispage you are changing the target height so if you use \enlargethispage{2cm} and the text is 2cm longer that is not a long page in that sense it is the (new) requested page size. If you do not want that do not use \enlargethispage as that is the sole purpose of that command.  Your test file only gets one warning as only one page is shorter than the requested target size.
